# Some values are converted into different format IN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

We are inserting data from Excel file to SQL server using SSIS.  My table have TelphoneNo field but when we inserted data into SQL table some values are converted into different format. There 10k records having wrong data. Can you please help me to query to update data in sql server.
Example: Source Value: 13902479195
                Destination Value: 1.39025e+010
Can you please help me to query to update data in sql server

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Also check in Excel the format of the column...for example TeleponeNo field in Excel may be a number but you actually want it as text

Answer (score 1):

Change the cell format (in Excel) to "0"

Like `=TEXT(A1, "0")`

Also sql decides data type from excel's first 5-10 rows.

Check data type in column map in sql import wizard. If you are getting different data type then insert some dummy rows in start in excel.

For example you have column that contains long text in some rows but in first 5-10 rows it contains small text then sql will consider data type nvarchar(255). In order to make it nvarchar(max) you have to create first 2-3 dummy rows with long text in excel.

Comment: I need to correct data in Sql server table. data already imported in Sql server.

Comment: try to change column data type to nvarchar then change/cast it in INT

Comment: You will not be able to fix this data in SQL server.  The precision is lost in the scientific notation format.  If you convert that value to real or float, for example, SQL will just move the decimal place 10 places to the right and add fill in 0s for what it doesn't know Convert(float, '1.39025e+010') = 13902500000